# getting a specific row of multiple csv's and writing to a new csv

Tags: python, csv, scripting

Have had a good search but can't quite find what I'm looking for. I have a number of csv files printed by a CFD simulation. The goal of my python script was to:

- get the final row of each csv and
- add the rows to a new file with the filename added to the start of each row

Currently I have

```
if file.endswith(".csv"):

    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        tsrNum = file.translate(None, '.csv')
        print(tsrNum + ', ' + ', '.join(list(csv.reader(f))[-1]))
```

Which prints the correct values into the terminal, but I have to manually and paste it into a new file.

Can somebody help with the last step? I'm not familiar enough with the syntax of python, certainly on my to-do list once I finish this CFD project as so far it's been fantastic when I've managed to implement it correctly. I tried using loops and `csv.dictWriter`, but with little success.

EDIT

I couldn't get the posted solution working. Here's the code a guy helped me make

```
import csv
import os
import glob

# get a list of the input files, all CSVs in current folder
infiles = glob.glob("*.csv")
# open output file
ofile = open('outputFile.csv', "w")
# column names
fieldnames = ['parameter','time', 'cp', 'cd']
# access it as a dictionary for easy access
writer = csv.DictWriter(ofile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
# output file header
writer.writeheader()
# iterate through list of input files
for ifilename in infiles:
    # open input file
    ifile = open(ifilename, "rb+")
    # access it as a dictionary for easy access
    reader = csv.DictReader(ifile)
    # get the rows in reverse order
    rows = list(reader)
    rows.reverse()
    # get the last row
    row = rows[0]
    # output row to output csv
    writer.writerow({'parameter': ifilename.translate(None, '.csv'), 'time': row['time'], 'cp': row['cp'], 'cd': row['cd']})
    # close input file
    ifile.close()

# close output file
ofile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Split your problem in smaller pieces:

- looping over directory
- getting last line
- writing to your new csv.

I have tried to be very verbose, so that you should try to do something like this:

```
   import os

    def get_last_line_of_this_file(filename):
        with open(filename) as f:
            for line in f:
                pass
            return line

    def get_all_csv_filenames(directory):
        for filename in os.listdir(directory):
            if filename.endswith('.csv'):
                yield filename

    def write_your_new_csv_file(new_filename):
        with open(new_filename, 'w') as writer:
            for filename in get_all_csv_filenames('now the path to your dir'):
                last_line = get_last_line_of_this_file(filename)
                writer.write(filename + ' ' + last_line)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        write_your_new_csv_file('your_created_filename.csv')
```

Comment: In my next project, I will need you as syntax checker :-) I meant the code as example and wrote it in a hurry. But thanks, I have corrected it.

Comment: I just copy/pasted it and ran it, nothing special. One last thing, OP seems to want to write out a new csv file, but you are adding a blank space in between `filename` and `last_line`, shouldn't it be `filename + ', ' + last_line`?

Comment: I do not know in which specific format the file should look like for the original poster. I meant to help him with with the restructuring of the problem. Id did not mean to solve this special issue. It would be trivially for him to change this part to his needs.

Comment: I got these. He was able to get the right values in the csv and complaining how to achieve this for all csv files in a given directory. My code should give him enough to get his job done. All he has to do is to put csv.reader(f))[-1] in the right place :-)